# Search for users using Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

Is this possible to use twitter api for searching by user's real name?

I have been trying the following code:

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=' . $firstName . $lastName, false, $context);
```

But it just returns false. Is there a way to do what I want?

I couldn't find anything in their documentation, the only thing I've found is this one, nothing more.

Comment: Try `echo $firstName . $lastName`. What do you notice?

Comment: Proper name of the user, like AlexNovak

Comment: I think the user's proper name is Alex Novak, not AlexNovak.

Comment: олегшендецкий for my test case